# I need help on creating a selenium script that contains Post request method links

Tags: java, selenium

What I'm trying to create is a `findelement().click` code that clicks on a button containing a Post Method link. The problem is I'm not too sure on how to create the code. Please refer to the screenshot below
[image: screenshot]

According to the attached screenshot, the section with the blue highlighting contains the `href` link that I want to put in my `findelement().click` code. I've tried the following script to no avail. `driver.findElement(By.xpath(//a[@href ='link shown in the screenshot']")).click();`

How do I access a page by clicking a button, in which the url is formatted as Post?

Edit: The one that I meant was the one with blue highlights, not the one that says "Bank of America". Apologies for the misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure, this will work:

```
WebElement BankOfAmerica = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Bank of America"));
BankOfAmerica.click();
```

Or with waiting, if page is beeing loaded.

```
    WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    WebElement BankOfAmerica = wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable)(By.linkText("Bank of America"));
    BankOfAmerica.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply find the element by linkText. The linkText method can be used when ever there is a link present or **a attribute** is present in the html file.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Bank of America")).click()
```

- Your current approach might not work since there are multiple href attribute and it might be possible that your xpath is wrong. To  verify whether your xpath is right or not  go to chrome console and check it by:--

  **$x("your xpath") //use single quotes within xpath**

This should not be undefined.

- In case you want to add wait in your scripy you can use explicit or implicit wait. [Selenium Wait](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html)

You can go for implicit wait in your case. It can be used in following way:--

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Bank of America")).click()
```

*Packages that you will require are:--*

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```